# split utf8 strings into parts with regexp

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I need to find in text strings, which start with `=?` and ends with `?=` and translate them. I ended with such an expression :

```
re.sub('=\?[\w\?\-\/=\+\:\;_\,\[\]\(\)\<\>]+\?=', decode_match, string)
```

It works in 95% cases, but it fails with similar strings:

```
=?utf-8asdfaDDS23=eFF?=-=?utf-8?eadf-,=?=
```

Can someone try to help ?

Comment: Are you sure your input looks like this?

Comment: I like jswolf's answer for its simplicity, but if you add a lazy quantifier after the plus symbol of your original regex (i.e., `'=\?[\w\?\-\/=\+\:\;_\,\[\]\(\)\<\>]+?\?=')`, it should also work (as tested here: http://ideone.com/601LA)

Comment: Then it's better '=\?(?:[\w\?\-\/=\+\:\;_\,\[\]\(\)\<\>]+?)\?='

Comment: I see no point in making it a non-capture group if you want the entire matching string (including delimiters). If you just want the tokens (the text in between the delimiters), then leave it as a capture group as shown in the ideone test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the case where you have ? without matching a ?= in your pattern

```
'=\?(?:[^?]|\?[^=])+\?='
```

Comment: Thanks!Can you explain this regexp?

Comment: Well, first you match the =?, then you match one or more of either a character that is not a ? with the [^?] or a ? and the next character that is not a = with the \?[^=]. The (?:) is a non-capturing grouping, so it's the same as using parens without getting the output variables.

Comment: That won't work if the last character before the delimiter is `?` (e.g. `=?utf-8asdf??=`).  Your negated character class (`[^=]`) should be a negative lookahead (`(?!=)`).

Comment: @Alan Agreed... You could also allow for a possible ? before the end delimiter for the fun `'=\?(?:[^?]|\?[^=])+\?*\?='`

Comment: No, the `\?[^=]` will still consume both question marks before the `\?*\?=` sees them.

Answer (score 0):

Does `str.split('=?')` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write ? :

```
re.sub('=\?.+?\?=', decode_match, string)
```

This regex will match two times in '=?utf-8asdfaDDS23=eFF?=-=?utf-8?eadf-,=?='

```
'=?utf-8asdfaDDS23=eFF?='

'=?utf-8?eadf-,=?='
```

Is it what you want? When evoking a failure, you should give it with more precision.